# Implementing interface properties in interfaces

Tags: c#, .net

I need to create a dll file which contains all the interfaces of the classes but doesn't contain any class.
Because I use these interfaces for a lot of classes it's must be like that:

```
public interface IClassA
{
    string Word { get; }
}

public interface ITest<TClassA> where TClassA : IClassA
{
    TClassA A { get; }
}
```

Example of two classes that implements these interfaces the way I want:

```
public class ClassA : IClassA
{
    public string Word
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    public string Sentence
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    public ClassA(string word, string sentence)
    {
        this.Word = word;
        this.Sentence = sentence;
    }
}

public class Test : ITest<ClassA>
{
    public ClassA A
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    public Test(ClassA a)
    {
        this.A = a;
    }
}
```

And I want to do something like that in the main program:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ClassA a = new ClassA("hey", "hey world!");
    Test t = new Test(a);

    Print((ITest<IClassA>)t);        
}

public static void Print(ITest<IClassA> t)
{
    Console.WriteLine(t.A.Word);
}
```

But this casting: `(ITest<IClassA>)t` makes a run time error.
How can I solve it?
thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You should declare `Test` as

```
public class Test : ITest<IClassA>
```

instead of `ITest<ClassA>`.

Or declare `ITest<TClassA>` to be covariant on `TClassA`:

```
public interface ITest<out TClassA> where TClassA : IClassA
```

Answer (score 1):

The `Test`-class implements the *concrete* `ClassA` (`public class Test : ITest<ClassA>`).

So you're trying to cast an `ITest<ClassA>` to `ITest<IClassA>` which obviously fails.

If you let the `Test`-class implement `IClassA`, the cast works:

```
public class Test : ITest<IClassA>
{
    public IClassA A
    {
        get; private set;
    }

    public Test(IClassA a)
    {
        this.A = a;
    }
}
```

Comment: I want the Test class to have a property of ClassA and not IClassA, It's not possible?

Comment: Yes, it is. Take a look @Thomas' [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40069043/594832): If `ITest<TClassA>` is covariant, it's possible: https://dotnetfiddle.net/KKkktG